# javascript: how to add an attribute to a child element ONLY if a parent element is active AND child element has a certain class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, syntax, slickgrid

I'm trying to recreate a grid carousel slider with using 2 one-row sliders instead of 1 two-row slider,

because I want to highlight only the single element that is "centered" AND "active" and in a two-row slider 2 elements are "centered" and "active".

I've run into two problems, because frankly my javascript is not that good.

Check out this pen
[http://codepen.io/mathiasvanderbrempt/pen/zGpGvd

js:
    $('.carousel:focus .frame.slick-center').css('border', '1px solid red');

2nd problem:

This would go with a event listener for scroll direction to make the slider "focused" to allow for directional arrow use (left and right).
meaning: if I would press arrow up, the window would move up(or can you cancel this?) and the active slider would be the top one, giving the ability to use arrow left and arrow right to navigate straight away, and vice versa.
  `[1]:` http://codepen.io/mathiasvanderbrempt/pen/zGpGvd

Comment: What does `= active` mean? Is that a global variable that holds the active element?

Comment: Is a class added to the active element?

Comment: Please show the JS you attempted, and explain the 2 problems you ran into with it? You'll learn better if we can explain where you went wrong than if we just write the code for you.

Comment: I tried different things but didnt document every attempt. this was my most recent try, I know what to write, but seem to be making syntax errors often.. 
`$('.carousel').object.hasFocus(function()) {
        $('.slick-center').attr('background', 'red');
    } else {
        false
      }
});`

Comment: Please put code in the question so it's readable

Comment: There's no `.object` accessor in jQuery. Everything in jQuery is methods that you call as functions, not property accessors. There's also no `.hasFocus()` method.

Comment: You have an extra `)` between `function ()` and `{` -- that's basic function syntax.

Comment: Shouldn't the code be inside an event handler, so it gets run when something happens to the page?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! you're absolutely right, I'll add a $(document).ready(function()) right? I also fixed the syntax error.

Comment: I will probably try to go from here tomorrow and see how it goes! thanks so much for your feedback tho.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS, not jQuery:

```
.carousel:focus .frame.slick-center {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that the active carousel has the focus?

Comment: that could be the problem. If i give it a css attribute on selector active it shows the change on click. but it doesnt show a change when use active, but it does put focus on the top or the bottom slider since i can only control 1 at a time with the directionals..

Comment: I did find this on codepen, and this could be the solution. [link](http://codepen.io/tjacobdesign/pen/qpxyh)

Comment: I've made a pen for this: http://codepen.io/mathiasvanderbrempt/pen/zGpGvd

Now I just need a way to apply the css to the .frame.slick-center class

Comment: You need to put the code into an event handler. Also, it should presumably remove the red background from all the other frames.

Comment: I tried `$(document).ready(function() {` but that doesnt seem to work... What kind of event handler would you suggest if I wanted to load this on document ready?

Comment: Don't you want to do this whenever the user changes the active carousel? That's the event I'm talking about.

Comment: I'm not really following, cause the css i want to add is just extra to the (active) slider element with the class .slick-center, which means it is just the centered slide that should get the red background/border.. so it shouldn't be provoked by an event imo... it will change automatically since the class .slick-center changes to with every slide

Comment: If you want it to automatically follow the class changes without re-running the jQuery code, put it into your CSS, not Javascript. I've updated the answer.

Comment: that css didnt work, although I feel we're on the right track. I've changed the css and added the tabindex property to the .frame.slick-center instead of the .carousel, making only the middle on highlighted when its active, but I should find this effect to be valid whenever the .carousel is active, have a look at my pen. Also need to get rid of that blue shadow when active.

Comment: If the CSS didn't work, I suspect the problem is that the active carousel doesn't actually have the keyboard focus. I took that from your question, and assumed you knew what you were doing in that respect. I'm not an expert on the carousel plugin you're using.